# Component is rendering one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to press sort twice for the items to be rendered, and they are rendered with what should've been rendered on the first press. So it's one step behind. Any idea why it is not being rendered on the first press and why it's one step behind?

I tried making it asynchronous, I tried making a loading state and then render, but everything to no effect.

Here is my code:

```
import "./productlist.scss";
import ProductCard from "../../../../Main Page Components/Trending Now/Product/ProductCard";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const ProductList = (props) => {
  const sortType = useSelector((state) => state.sort).sortType;
  const [sortedProducts, setSortedProducts] = useState(props.products);
  // const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSortedProducts(sortProducts(sortedProducts, sortType));
  }, [sortType, sortedProducts]);

  const sortProducts = (products, sortMode) => {
    console.log("sortMode", sortMode);
    switch (sortMode) {
      case "A-Z":
        return products.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

      case "Z-A":
        return products.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)).reverse();

      case "default":
        return products;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="product-list padding">
      <div className="product-list-contents">
        {sortedProducts.map((singleProduct) => {
          console.log("singleProduct", singleProduct.name);
          // if(product.categories[0].name.slice(0,1).toLowerCase() === props.category){
          return (
            <Link
              to={`/product/${singleProduct.sku}`}
              className="product-list-link"
              key={singleProduct.sku}
            >
              <ProductCard product={singleProduct} />
            </Link>
          );
          // )}
          // }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `useEffect` is both setting and listening to `sortedProducts` which might be causing error.

Assuming that `sortedProducts` is based on `products` from `props`, and `sortType` is updated by `useSelector`, perhaps this component can sort `props.products` without keeping a state and `useEffect`. For a rough example:

```
const ProductList = (props) => {
  const { sortType } = useSelector((state) => state.sort);
  const sortProducts = (products, sortMode) => {
    console.log("sortMode", sortMode);
    switch (sortMode) {
      case "A-Z":
        return products.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
      case "Z-A":
        return products.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)).reverse();
      case "default":
        return products;
    }
  };
  const sortedProducts = sortProducts(props.products, sortType);

  return (
    <div className="product-list padding">
      <div className="product-list-contents">
        {sortedProducts.map((singleProduct) => {
          console.log("singleProduct", singleProduct.name);
          // if(product.categories[0].name.slice(0,1).toLowerCase() === props.category){
          return (
            <Link
              to={`/product/${singleProduct.sku}`}
              className="product-list-link"
              key={singleProduct.sku}
            >
              <ProductCard product={singleProduct} />
            </Link>
          );
          // )}
          // }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```